# React module cannot be found?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a app with create-react-app. But, I cant see why its keeps saying `./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/home/home' in ...`

My project structure is:

[image]

Code for the app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './components/home/home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Home />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

    state = {
       text: "Lorem",
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                    <div className="container">{this.state.text}
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

I have imported components in previous projects the same way? and it's worked fine.

Comment: I just tried your code with codesandbox.io and it's working

Comment: This should not be breaking. It may sound stupid but can you try restarting your server?

Comment: Re-started but same message....

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your project aswell? also your home folder has no undescore before its name unlike other folders maybe thats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So I used `npx create-react-app` to create this app. Looks like its something to do with that. Because when I used `npm -g create-react-app` and then `create-react-app my-app` its working fine.